# About 2's complement for natural numbers to binary

Tags: computer-science, twos-complement

I know how to convert a number into binary with 2's complement but I am still confused on the notion of it.

Do we use 2's complement only when we are converting negative numbers into binary?

Any help would be great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two's complement notation for negative numbers really depends on a fixed-length encoding to be well-defined. Why? It requires that leading zeroes be semantically relevant. Variable-length encodings (like in mathematics generally) ignore leading zeroes: 0101 and 101 are the same number. However, in two's complement, one of these numbers is positive (0101 = 5 in a 4-bit two's complement notation) and the other negative (101 = -3 in a 3-bit two's complement notation). So you really must specify the container size for two's complement to be meaningful.

Now that this is out of the way, the answer to your question becomes clearer. Any given string of bits of length `k` is a number in a `k`-bit two's complement notation. The number is positive if and only if the most significant bit is zero. Any given "positive" number you have is only positive with respect to any given two's complement notation if it doesn't require the `k`th bit be set, where `k` is the number of bits in your notation. For example, in a 4-bit two's complement notation, the "positive" number 8 ( = 1000) cannot be represented and, if you tried to do it anyway, the number would be interpreted as -8 ( = 1000). The representable range would be [-8, 7] = [1000, 0111].